# Java runnable application sinlgeton issue

Tags: java, singleton, runnable

I'm blocked with a problem using a singleton, I will explain the problem after the code.

**Class Launcher**

```
    public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Controleur ctr = Controleur.getInstance();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**class Controleur**

```
public class Controleur {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private EcranPrincipal EP;
    private PremierEcran PE;

    public Controleur() {

        if(!VerifierFichier()){
            PE = new PremierEcran();
            PE.setVisible(true);
        }
        else
            lancerEcranPrincipal();
    }

    private static Controleur INSTANCE = null;

    public static Controleur getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new Controleur();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void lancerEcranPrincipal(){
        try{
            PE.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        }catch(Exception e){}

        EP = new EcranPrincipal();
    }

    public void setMDP(String mdp1){
        new MotDePasse(mdp1);
    }

    public void setVille(String nomVilleFormat) {
        FichierVille.getInstance(nomVilleFormat);
    }

    public String getNomVille() {
        String nomVille = FichierVille.getInstance("").getNomFichier();
        return "";
    }

    public boolean VerifierFichier(){
        File mdpfile;

        mdpfile = new File("data/MotDePasse.dat");
        if(mdpfile.exists() && mdpfile.isFile()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "true");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "false");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Class EcranPrincipal**

```
public class EcranPrincipal extends JFrame{
 public EcranPrincipal(){
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            setUndecorated(true);
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);

            JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
            pane.setLayout(gridbag);
            pane.setBackground(Color.white);

            JTextPane Textmdp = new JTextPane();
            String name = Controleur.getInstance().getNomVille();
            Textmdp.setText("ville: ");
            Textmdp.setEditable(false);
    }
 }
```

When the singleton was already instanced, in the class "EcranPrincipal", I call the instance Singleton of class "controleur":

```
        String name = Controleur.getInstance().getNomVille();
```

The big problem here is that line, because it give as result the execution on this line

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "true");
```

Who is inside the fonction VerifierFichier() at "Controleur" class. So, I have infinite times the showMessageDialog. My question is why my singleton doesn't execute as I wanted.
Precisely, i want my variable "name" to go obtain the information in the function "getNomVille()".

Help me please.

Thanks in advance.